# How to not renew access token in Amplify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My app uses React.js, Amplify and Cognito and it needs to refresh access token when it is still valid (if user uses the app, it refreshes  the access token) but if the user does not use the app and the access token is expired (after 1 hour) I wanted it to force logout the user. I couldn't find an method to get the access token expiration time without refreshing the access token automatically (because with it I could check if expiration has been reached)

Obs: I can't set the refresh token to one hour, because some processes require the user to stay logged in more than this

Obs2: Everytime an user try to access a page, the page call Auth.currentSession to verify users info through idtoken

Tried:

```
const userSession = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const signInUserSession = userSession.signInUserSession;

        const idToken = signInUserSession.idToken;

        const expirationTime = new Date(idToken.payload.exp * 1000);

        if (new Date() < expirationTime) {
          console.log("not expired");
          const user = await Auth.currentSession();

          setIsAuthenticated(true);
          setAuth(user);
        } else {
          console.log("expired");
          Auth.signOut();
        }
```

Expected:
User logout after 1 hour of inactivity

Got:
Refresh token refreshed access token after 1 hour (1 hour is the access token lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is expected behaviour of oauth2 or OIDC.

You can reduce the ttl of the `access_token` to 20 minutes, and the ttl of the `refresh_token` to 1 hour. That would logout **ANY** user after 1 hour without activity.

If you want to logout only in specific use cases, you need to build an inactivity tracker. If a time limit has reached you remove all tokens from your app, and you are loggedout. And if your IDP has a logout or revoke url, you can even call that to revoke the refresh_token to prevent any further use of that token. Since sometimes your refresh_token can be valid for months!

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your help!

The problem is, sometimes a user needs to upload an video of many gbs, and this could result in an 1 hour upload or more (depending on the user's network), so if the upload reaches 1.5h, the refresh token would not maintain the session

Comment: And if I use and inactivity tracker, it would rely on idle timeout, right? So if the user closes the tab an reopens after 1 hour, the timer will reset and the session will refresh and the user will not logout

Comment: The inactivity tracker need to take the previous date in account.  So if the time between `now` and the previous registered dat is longer than 1 hour then you drop the tokens. 
If your upload takes over 1 hour, your activity tracker either need to track network traffic, or use a ping (or websocket) to keep track of the connectivity.

Comment: I understand. In that case I would need to register the previous date, probably in the db to persist it. Considering this, I could store the Access token expiration time and use it also.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Depending on how you've built your application. If you store the tokens in the server session, do you don't have to expose your tokens to a browser, you can just store the date in the session. And if you are using sessions, keep in mind to run logout and clear session data after the time has expired.